# Group method docstrings in sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

Is it possible to group several method docstrings with sphinx using it's autodoc capabilities, so that they are listed together?

```
class Test(object):
    def a(self):
        """A method of group foo."""

    def b(self):
        """A method of group bar."""

    def c(self):
        """A method of group bar."""

    def d(self):
        """A method of group foo."""
```

In the generated documentation a and d should be listed together, aswell as b and c.

Comment: I assume you mean with `autodoc`?  As, you can put anything you want in the `.rst` files...

Comment: @mgilson Thats what I meant. I will update the question to clarify.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48674189/docstring-for-groups-of-methods-in-sphinx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group the methods in the source module and configure Sphinx to output them in that order, using [`autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'`](http://sphinx-doc.org/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_member_order).

I am not aware of any other way to group members.